# How do I post long strings that contain special characters (like '&' specifically) via an AJAX request?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm looking to make a Contact/Query form, wherein the end user can send an email to the webmaster. The form has a 'textarea'  field, which captures long strings from the user, if I use AJAX to submit the form using GET method, my params tend to break if their is a special character, specifically '&' in the textarea's string..
I'm stuck please help!

Comment: Isn't this an abuse of HTTP/Rest to use GET to post data to the server?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript) SO question that explain how to encode an url in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Try calling [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Functions:encodeURIComponent) in your javascript when posting the request.

Comment: Don't use `escape`, it doesn't "work just fine" (unless your data *happens* to fall into the subset of characters which it handles OK). Use encodeURIComponent.

Comment: cool, I'm using the one you suggest..what special characters does 'escape' omit?

Comment: `@`, `+`, `/` ... Check this page out: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/ especially the table in section 3

Answer (score 0):

You can make the string URL safe using JavaScript urlencode...

```
var textToSend = encodeURIComponent(myform.myfield.value);
```

This will convert all special characters into URL encoded characters.

Comment: Are you sure that urlencode exist in javascript? Use encodeURIComponent()!

Comment: Don't use `escape`, it doesn't "work just fine" (unless your data *happens* to fall into the subset of characters which it handles OK). Use encodeURIComponent.

Comment: Yes, I was doing a lot of PHP that day - in JavaScript it is called encodeURIComponent!